# Issue with .htaccess file on MAMPstack

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have MAMPstack 5.4.9 installed on my mac and am not able to my .htaccess file to work. I am trying to do the simplest test to check and make sure it is working and it seems to be ignoring the file. When I first creating the access file, my Mac did warn me indicating any file that starts with a ( . ) would be hidden, I am assuming that is just hidden in the finder so I cannot view it, the file should still exist to the programs installed.

In my root directory I have 3 files setup, test.html, test.php, and my .htaccess file. I am simply trying to test the .htaccess file by redirecting the test.html to test.php. Instead of redirecting it just loads the test.html page with no changes to the URL.

**My https.conf file**

```
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so

<Directory "/Applications/MampStack.app/Contents/Resources/app/apache2/cgi-bin">
  AllowOverride All
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

**My .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?test.html$ test.php [L]
```

**My file structure**

```
htdocs
  test.html
  test.php
  .htaccess
```

Comment: Make sure if your `.htaccess` is enabled by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Tried your suggestion and I did indeed get a 500 error, so it is reading the .htaccess file but it is not executing the rule... I checked the phpinfo() as well and confirmed again that mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Try this rule in your `.htaccess`: `RewriteRule ^/?test.html$ /test.php [L,R]` and then open this URI: `/test.html` and see if that changes the URI to `/test.php` OR not?

Comment: I read that I need to set the rewritebase so I updated the super simple rule I have set to the following. It is still not working, 500 error.                                                                             RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test.html$ index.php

Comment: Can you check Apache error log. I suspect mod_rewrite isn't enabled.

Comment: I don't think I have access to that, it is shared hosting. Would I still receive a 500 error when putting gibberish in the .htaccess file if mod_rewrite was not enabled?

Comment: Yes definitely you will get 500 in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so the issue was with my RewriteBase. Based on some forum posts I saw on my hosts website, other users suggested a RewriteBase '/', which is what I was using. I had to specify the specific sub-folder I was running the .htaccess file in which was '/dev3/'.

This solved my issue.

```
RewriteBase /dev3/
```